# How to set an int value depending on alphabetical sort order

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-update, sql-order-by, row-number

I'm a SQL noob and I need syntax help on how do I use a SET command to assign the values of my SortOrder Column. The below code does not Update the table but it's how I would like it to look (all SortOrder values are set to 0). I could go through manually but looking for a quick alternative (the data set is a bit bigger).

```
Select ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Name ASC) AS SortOrder, Name
From DesignColours

SortOrder |Name
1          Beige
2          Black
3          Blue
4          Brown
5          Copper
```

Thanks for the help

Comment: Please tag your DBMS

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can benefit from cte like below, assuming you are using SQL Server and your original table has already a column like SortOrder:

```
;with cte (SortOrder, Name) as (
   Select ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Name ASC) AS SortOrder, Name
   From DesignColours
)
update d
set d.SortOrder = cte.SortOrder
from DesignColours d
inner join cte on d.Name = cte.Name
```

If there is no SortOrder column already existing, you can do:

```
ALTER TABLE DesignColours
ADD SortOrder int
GO
```

The regular usage of update statement is:

```
UPDATE tablename
set columnName = yourvalue
where <yourrule>
```

Ref: https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_update.asp

Comment: Yes my SortOrder column did exist so I appreciate both solutions. Thank you very much, will look up this cte - it's worked no problem

Comment: You are welcome, if my answer works for you I'd appreciate if you select it as the correct answer by clicking the tick on the left.

Answer (score 5):

```
update a
set a.SortOrder = b.SortOrder
from DesignColours a
join 
(Select ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Name ASC) AS SortOrder, Name
   From DesignColours)b
on a.Name = b.Name
```